# Contact Form 7 - press button to validate fieldset

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form

I've used Contact form 7 (wordpress plugin) to create a single form with multiple fieldsets.

The fieldsets are then split (using jquery) like this: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

What I want to do is validate all the fields in the fieldset (without submitting the form) - is there a way to
1) validate fields using the validation in contact form 7 manually?
2) specify which fields to validate (based on only those in a fieldset)?

Ideally I want to be able to do it with flexibility in mind as I will be creating 2 or 3 other forms that perform the same way.

Edit: by validate I mean check that the field is:

a) filled in, if it's a required field

b) valid data (so making sure its an email address etc).

My problem is I want to validate the fields manually, without submitting the form, so I can stop them progressing on to the next step of form filling if they've not completed the current fieldset of fields correctly.

Carl

Answer (score 0):

What you want to validate ? 
If you want to validate an email address. You should write input `type = email` in your email textbox. 
HTML will validate textbox itself, that it should be in email format.
Same as for digits. If you want to validate that a textbox should contain only number. 
Use input `type = number` on your textbox.

Here is an Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/z9b5mcur/1/

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Please see edits. Also I have a form that validates on completion, but because I'm developing a multi-step form (see link I attached originally) I want to validate the current screen before moving on to next.